# Android - Volley and keeping the Sessioncookie

Tags: android, android-volley

Many different questions about this, but mine is a little different.

I need to do a kind of "screenscraping" from an existing website. Im logging in to the site. Saving cookievariable in my shareprefs and using this to navigate through the website and presenting them how I want it in my app by collecting the input fields and values.

Anyway. So far so good. Im able to log in -> save cookie -> read website as logged in user.

Problem : Doing POST on the same website. Here the cookie seems to get lost somewhere. Website cant read it or doesnt approve it.

```
// onCreate
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
    SESSIONID = "Cookievariable";
    loadWebSite();

}

// Read website
private void loadWebSite(){
String url = "http://somewebsite";

RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(act);

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
    new Response.Listener<String>()
    {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Website loaded OK!
      }
     },
    ) {

        // Set headers
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Cookie", SESSIONID);
            Log.d("PARAMS", params.toString());
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

}

```
// Later on - Send post when button clicked
private void sendPost(){

    String url = "http://somewebsite";
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(act);

StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
    new Response.Listener<String>()
    {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(String response) {
        // POST SENT - But something wrong with session.
      }
     },
    ) {
        // Set POST params
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
             Map<String, String>  postParams = new HashMap<>();
             postParams.put("SomeParam", "Someparamhere");
             return postParams;
        }
        // Set headers
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Cookie", SESSIONID);
            Log.d("PARAMS", params.toString());
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question : The problem was related to the cookieHandler somehow.

I moved it out from the fragment and into the my Main Activity / Nav Activity and it seemed to do the trick.

CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());